# Convert Word Doc to PDF with new File Name and Attach to New Email

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames

I am trying to add a document to an email as a PDF. I am trying to change the file name to include the date which is stored in a table in the Word document.

I can create the email but the script gives me an error when it tries to export.

How can I attach the file as a PDF with a file name with the date pulled from the table in Word?

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document

Dim DateField       As String
Dim desktoploc      As String
Dim mypath          As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save


'Pull date from table and change format
DateField = Format(Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 4).Range.Text, "yyyymmdd")

'Pull line number and subject names from table 1 and table 2 in word to add to subject.
Dim linenum As Word.Range, subject1 As Word.Range, subjec2 As Word.Range

'Need to remove hidden line breaks from tables in word in order to fit on subject line of email
Set linenum = Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
linenum.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
Set subject1 = Doc.Content.Tables(2).Cell(2, 1).Range
subject1.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
Set subjec2 = Doc.Content.Tables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range
subjec2.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1

'Create PDF File
Dim file_name       As String
Dim NewFileName     As String

NewFileName = "Load Limits Subjects " & linenum & " " & DateField

file_name = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & Left(ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1) & NewFileName & ".pdf"

'This is where I keep getting the error.....

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=file_name, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

   
With EmailItem
    .Display
    .Subject = "Limit Notification - Subject " & linenum & " #line #" & linenum & _
    " #" & subject1.Text & " #" & subjec2.Text & vbCrLf
    .Body = "Please see the attached Limit Notification for Subject " & linenum.Text & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "Let me know if you have any questions." & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "Thank you," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT SIGNATURE HERE"
    
'Update Recipient List here:
    .To = "LineEmail@email.com; "
    .CC = "Another Email@demail.com"
    '.Importance = olImportanceNormal
    
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "an error" is not a useful description of what happens when your code runs.  What error do you get, and on which line exactly?

Comment: Try `debug.print file_name` - does it look like a valid file path/name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple flaws, including:

1. Your DateField string is trying to convert something that includes a table cell's end-of-cell marker into an ISO-format date
2. Your code is not validating the NewFileName string as a filename.
3. Your code is trying to to attach the document to the email, not the pdf.
4. Your code is referencing ActiveDocument (which may no longer be the same as Doc) when creating path etc. for the new filename.

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim i               As Long
Dim NewFileName     As String
Dim MailSubject     As String
Dim MailBody        As String
Const StrNoChr      As String = """*./\:?|"
NewFileName = " Load Limits Subjects "
MailSubject = "Limit Notification - Subject "
MailBody = "Please see the attached Limit Notification for Subject "

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set Doc = ActiveDocument
With Doc
  .Save
  Set Rng = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  NewFileName = NewFileName & Rng.Text & " "
  MailSubject = MailSubject & Rng.Text & " #line #" & Rng.Text & " #"
  MailBody = MailBody & Rng.Text
  Set Rng = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 4).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  NewFileName = NewFileName & Format(Rng.Text, "YYYYMMDD")
  Set Rng = .Tables(2).Cell(2, 1).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  MailSubject = MailSubject & Rng.Text
  Set Rng = .Tables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  MailSubject = MailSubject & Rng.Text
  For i = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
    NewFileName = Replace(NewFileName, Mid(StrNoChr, i, 1), "_")
  Next
  NewFileName = Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0) & NewFileName & ".pdf"
  SaveAs2 FileName:=NewFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End With


MailBody = MailBody & vbCrLf & _
  "" & vbCrLf & _
  "Let me know if you have any questions." & vbCrLf & _
  "" & vbCrLf & _
  "Thank you," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
  "INSERT SIGNATURE HERE"

With EmailItem
    .Display
    .Subject = MailSubject
    .Body = MailBody
    
'Update Recipient List here:
    .To = "LineEmail@email.com; "
    .CC = "Another Email@demail.com"
    '.Importance = olImportanceNormal
    
    .Attachments.Add NewFileName
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this code looks and works great.  When copying and pasting everything ran smoothly.  I made some changes to be specific to my file and now I am just trying to work through the errors I got there.  Thanks for taking a look and this great solution!